# Cross-Origin Request Blocked when using http request

Tags: angular, http, cross-domain

I try to make a http request to this address in angular2

http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/398/teams

It works fine until today I got an error message saying :

*Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.*

While I can access this url through browser. What could the problem be? What is the difference bettween making this http request through browser and using angular2. For my chrome browser I also install the cors extension on chrome.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is config the CORS on the server.

Answer (score 0):

it turns our the cors chrome extension is not woring properly and once I restart it everything works again.

Another solution is to use a proxy or add a cors header on the server.